# Node.js Mongoose: Include excluded fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  salt: {
    type: String,
    select: false
  },
  facebook: {},
  google: {}
});
```

Question. I've set salt default excluded, how to include it in response? If i would set `this.findOne({}, 'salt')` it will return ONLY salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'+salt'` to override the default without excluding other fields:

```
this.findOne({}, '+salt')
```

Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).